# spring gwt - cannot add restful webservice - RequestMapping exception

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I started a gwt spring 3 project thought spring roo. Then I took roo off the project and implemented spring security, everything working as expected.

But I am having a problem to add restful controllers to my project. Basically it should have been easy, but, since I am using GWT, maybe it has to do with some of the configurations.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.consumes()[Ljava/lang/String;

I thought this would mean I am missing some kind of dependency, but I checked, I am using all spring dependencies possible and required in all example projects that I researched, so I am assuming its another thing.

My restful controller below

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Controller
public class TestControler {

   @RequestMapping("/test")
   @ResponseBody
   public String getAll() {
      return "aba";
   }
```

My `web.xml`

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml 
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>    

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>    

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>    

    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>requestFactory</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myapp.CustomRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>       

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>requestFactory</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

My servlet spring mvc config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.ufsc.inf.citymobile"
    use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"
    mapping="/resources/**" />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
        p:paramName="lang" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure" />

<bean       class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
    id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"
    id="themeSource" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver"
    id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard" />

<bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
    p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    id="multipartResolver" />
```

My application context

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

<context:spring-configured />

<context:component-scan base-package="br.ufsc.inf.citymobile">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
        type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I removed the vast amount of comments from your XML files. They were doing nothing for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Spring is too old.

The exception is complaining about a missing method (`RequestMapping.consume`), which was only introduced in Spring 3.1.  It's not in Spring 3.0.

You need to upgrade to Spring 3.1

Comment: humm, interesting, my config right now @ <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>  I will try to change the release.

Comment: @Lucas: You may have duplicates on your classpath, somehow, with multiple Spring versions.

Comment: Exactly, I had duplicated, humm, probably some lib is duplicating the spring-web and spring-tx, those are duplicated as version 3.0.6 and 3.1.0 - So, thank you guys, never thought about this.